# Can we display details of branch owner who committed the change along with last committed date in Hygieia

Tags: git, jenkins, devops, dashboard, hygieia

We have 4 projects in GIT hub. Lets assume them as A1, A2, A3 & A4. For all the four projects we have setup corresponding Multibranch jenkins pipeline jobs. Once I setup dashboard I would like to display data of no.of commits in a week, last committed date with owner. Jenkins URL etc. Is it possible with Hygieia?

And also kindly let me know if I can make use of any other database other than Mongo DB.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. On hygieia 'repo widget', when you click the data points in graph - it will show your COMMIT INFO such as HASH, AUTHOR, MESSAGE and DATE/TIME
[image: hygieia-code-repo-widget]